# Mixing anyhow::Result with std::io::Result

Tags: rust, anyhow

Can anyone help me understand why this code compiles fine:

```
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};
use anyhow::Result;

mod error;

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new())
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

while this doesn't compile:

```
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};
use anyhow::Result;

mod error;

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new())
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

with the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:1
  |
6 | #[actix_rt::main]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `anyhow::Error`, found struct `std::io::Error`
7 | async fn main() -> Result<()> {
  |                    ---------- expected `std::result::Result<(), anyhow::Error>` because of return type
  |
  = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, anyhow::Error>`
             found enum `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`
  = note: this error originates in an attribute macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What is fundamentally different between the two examples?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that the second example is returning `Result<(), std::io::Error>` which is returned by starting the server, whereas the first one is returning `Result<(), anyhow::Error>` in the form of `Ok(())`.

The reason the first example works is that the `?` operator (or the `try!` macro) performs a conversion from whatever error is returned to the error of the return type of the function.

From [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html):

> In case of the Err variant, it retrieves the inner error. try! then performs conversion using From. This provides automatic conversion between specialized errors and more general ones.

Comment: I see, I thought `?` just returned the inner error without touching it. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the same conversion that `anyhow` uses:

```rust
use actix_web::{App, HttpServer};
use anyhow::Result;

#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new())
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8080")?
        .run()
        .await.map_err(anyhow::Error::from)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`anyhow::Error` [implements `From<std::error::Error>`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.31/anyhow/struct.Error.html#impl-From%3CError%3E), but they are not the same thing.

In the first one the `?` is taking the `std::error::Error` from `run().await` and calling `anyhow::Error::from`. 
The second one is not.

Changing the return type of your method to

```
Result<(), std::error::Error>
```

fixes the issue.